# FTPClient connection with Java on AWS Virtual Machine

Tags: java

I'm trying to connect to my FTP server in Java SE 1.8. To do so I use this method :

```
private void connectFTP() {
    String server = "ftp.XXXXXXXXXX.site";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "XXXX";
        String pass = "XXXX";
        
        if(!ftpConnexionSuccess.get())
        {
             client = new FTPClient();
             client.configure(new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX));
             try {
                
                client.connect(server, port);

                ftpConnexionSuccess.set(client.login(user, pass));
                 
                 if (!ftpConnexionSuccess.get()) {
                     System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
                     return;
                     
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     System.out.println("LOGGED IN SERVER");
                     
                     client.changeWorkingDirectory("/crypto");
                    
                     
                    listenedFile = getListenedFile();
                    System.out.println(listenedFile.getName());
                    if(listenedFile != null)
                    {
                        baseFileTimeStamp.set(listenedFile.getTimestamp().getTimeInMillis());
                    }
                   System.out.println(baseFileTimeStamp);
                   
                
                 }
                 
                 
             } catch (Exception ex) { 
                
                System.err.println("FTP connection error : Sleeping for 5 seconds before trying again (" + ex.getMessage() + ")");
                ex.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                
                try {
                
                    client.disconnect();
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                connectFTP();
                
                
             }
        }
       
        
    }
```

It works great when I'm on Eclipse and when I export the app on my Windows 10.

Nonetheless, when I try to launch the app on my AWS Webmachine I get a null pointer exception at "listenedFile". The method to listen to this file is the one below.

```
private FTPFile getListenedFile() {
        
        FTPFile returnedFile = null;
        try {
            for(FTPFile file : client.listFiles())
            {
                if(file.getName().contains("filetolisten.txt"))
                    returnedFile = file;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
            
                client.disconnect();
                
            } catch (IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
            
            connectFTP();
            return getListenedFile();
            
        }
        
        return returnedFile;
    }
```

I thought it was because of the line

```
client.configure(new FTPClientConfig(FTPClientConfig.SYST_UNIX));
```

I tried to delete the line, and to replace SYST_UNIX with SYST_NT, but nothing worked.

I tried to delete the line, and to replace SYST_UNIX with SYST_NT, but nothing worked. Also updated Java, updated the common-nets library. Nothing worked

Comment: Try printing out the filenames in your `for` loop. It's probably not finding the required file, or the list is empty.

Comment: I tried and it seems that the FTP client is not able to fetch any file, the list is indeed empty